# SSL ERROR i cannot log into my yahoo account to ask a question using my account! help

Tags: yahoo

any one getting this error today?

The site's security certificate has expired!
You attempted to reach login.yahoo.com, but the server presented an expired certificate. No information is available to indicate whether that certificate has been compromised since its expiration. This means Google Chrome cannot guarantee that you are communicating with login.yahoo.com and not an attacker. You should not proceed.

Comment: Check your computer's time, looks like its not correct.

Comment: what has yahoo login got to do with computer time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSL certificate has an expiry time. login.yahoo.com expires January, 4th next year (2011).

Your browser compares this date with your local system's date. So check, if your system clock isn't wrong.

Comment: @isac You're right. Quite. Guess you got that "error message" from within a VM?

Comment: My last comment this year: try clearing your browser's cache, then check the time and retry...